# What are some of the considerations for putting electric guitar strings on a bass?

Tags: strings, bass-guitar

After watching the linked video it came clear that putting regular strings on a bass has some groovy effects, Im just curious as to how bass pickups are going to work with strings that operate on different frequencies?

Is there some other pitfalls to doing this or can you use it for some new sonic possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just curious as to how bass pickups are going to work with strings that operate on different frequencies.

There's no basic problem there. Simplistically-speaking, bass pickups will work on all the frequencies that guitar pickups do.

IMO the main difference you will get is a difference in the feel of the instrument, which you may find inspiring - or just awkward.

To get it working as well as possible, you'll probably need to re-do the instrument setup once it has the new string set on.

> Is there some other pitfalls to doing this?

watch for...

- overtightening guitar strings - if you tune a guitar string to the same pitch as usual on a longer instrument, you will have tightened it much more.
- buying strings that are too short (this is mentioned at the end of the video).